# How a shower head can affect water temperature?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, temperature, everyday-life, flow, turbulence

This is a real-life case, that I simply don't understand :)

A shower set is composed of a faucet $-$ that contains a mixer, a hose and a showerhead. The water comes from 2 pipes $-$ hot and cold. The sources are stable $-$ the water has constant pressure and temperature. Water comes through a mixer that is basically a 2 axis valve. On one axis (handle moved left $\leftrightarrow$ right) user selects how much water would come from which source, and on the other (up $\leftrightarrow$ down) the openness (overall strength of out-flowing water). Then, the water flows through a hose to the shower-head, which disperses the water in a nice rainy fashion. See diagram (with example mixer settings):
[image]

The shower set delivered water with temperature that varied significantly. In a moment water could be cold just to become scalding within a second. I was pretty sure that it is a problem with the mixer. So I replaced it, but it didn't help. So I checked all parts to find out that the shower-head is causing the problems. (I even installed it (only shower-head) in a different shower and the problem was observed there too)

And this is something I cannot comprehend. How shower-head which is far away from the mixer can influence the temperature? Water should be already mixed at the beginning of the hose. One more thing, the water flow was also significantly reduced by the shower-head, that reduction isn't linear it behaves more or less as in this diagram:
[image]

Comment: You seem to be experiencing a form of OR gate   Assuming that the situation is as you describe (stable input flows and temperatures) you may have independently (and belatedly) discovered the field of fluidic logic https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluidics

Answer (score 3):

I have experienced rather similar effects on several shower systems. The problem typically occurs when the mixer is working below its intended pressure or flow range.

My experience is that high water pressures and flow rates are less problematic than gentle flow. Where I have fitted a shower pump, the problem has gone away.

I once tried a "turbo" shower head, which spins to increase flow rate (a kind of half-hearted pump), and that helped a little.

Why? Fluid flow can be mathematically chaotic, which means that turbulence effects can be highly nonlinear and essentially unpredictable.

My suggestion would be that your shower head is reducing the flow rate below the mixer's design range and, because of this, the flow adjustment has become chaotic. Even a small adjustment can flip it from a state of turbulent and hence restricted hot flow to a similar state of cold flow.

But I am wide open to more expert explanations.